# picker view not loading items

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, mlab

I am currently having trouble with the pickerview as when I click play quiz on the app the picker view is not loading from the web service at all. The picker view should display the array of answers from the web service. The picker view is empty any ideas? Also the question is not loading from the web service as a text label?

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernamelabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemlabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!

public var totalQuestions: Int = 0
public var currentQuestion = 0
public var totalCorrect: Int = 0
var itemSelected: String = ""
@IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!
var LabelText = String()


var listQuestions = [[String: Any]]()
var titles: [String] = []
var qnames: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!
var quiz = QuestionList()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() //when the app is loaded


    let url:String =     "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/quiz/collections/question?apiKey=NT28RNl6jX3Ys0x5GJZ6mMSRQEcb_6KA"

    let urlRequest = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else{
            do{
                self.listQuestions = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(self.listQuestions)

                for elements in self.listQuestions {
                    for object in elements {
                        if object.key == "Answers" {
                            if let answers = object.value as? [String] {
                                self.titles = answers
                            }
                            if object.key == "Questions" {
                                if let questions = object.value as? String {
                                    self.qnames = questions
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()


}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1 //return one component from the picker
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    return titles.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->String?{


    return self.titles[row]


}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[row]

}

@IBAction func btnShareClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {

        let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        fbShare.setInitialText("You Scored " + itemlabel.text! + " on the IT Quiz")
        self.present(fbShare, animated:true, completion:nil)

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account", message: "Please login to Facebook",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}





}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ViewController` is missing the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol:

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {}
```

Make sure pickerView's `delegate` and `datasource` is set to the current `viewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() //when the app is loaded

    pickerview.delegate = self
    pickerview.dataSource = self
}
```

The `dataTask` is an async task, you should update the UI on the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

The final code should like this:

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernamelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!

    public var totalQuestions: Int = 0
    public var currentQuestion = 0
    public var totalCorrect: Int = 0
    var itemSelected: String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!
    var LabelText = String()


    var listQuestions = [[String: Any]]()
    var titles: [String] = []
    var qnames: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!
    var quiz = QuestionList()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // when the app is loaded

        pickerview.delegate = self
        pickerview.dataSource = self

        let url:String = "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/quiz/collections/question?apiKey=NT28RNl6jX3Ys0x5GJZ6mMSRQEcb_6KA"

        let urlRequest = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            else{
                do{
                    self.listQuestions = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    print(self.listQuestions)

                    for elements in self.listQuestions {
                        for object in elements {
                            if object.key == "Answers" {
                                if let answers = object.value as? [String] {
                                    self.titles = answers
                                }
                            }
                            if object.key == "Questions" {
                                if let questions = object.value as? String {
                                    self.qnames = questions
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
                        self.Question.text = self.qnames
                    }

                }catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1 //return one component from the picker
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return titles.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->String? {
        return self.titles[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

        itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[row]

    }

    @IBAction func btnShareClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {

            let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            fbShare.setInitialText("You Scored " + itemlabel.text! + " on the IT Quiz")
            self.present(fbShare, animated:true, completion:nil)

        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account", message: "Please login to Facebook",
                                          preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this is working but how do I get the question label to appear from the web service. The name of this in the web service is "Questions"? Thanks

Comment: I just updated the answer. Now, you can retrieve `Question` from the web service. I assumed the `Question` in your code is your question label that you want to display.

Comment: okay thanks and how about the function called did select row within the picker view

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: I want to know what row the user has selected but without doing this from any dummy data but the web service or the best way of implementing this?

Comment: You have an array of answers, you have a selected row in the `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`. So you can get the selected item with ease: `itemSelected = self.titles[row]`

Comment: okay thanks but how do I make the itemselected appear visible so you can see printed out what the user selects

Answer (score 0):

To get question label:

```
for object in elements {

      if let result = object["Questions"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

           print(result)

}
```